# What is the derivative of $y = \sin^3(4x)\cos^3(4x)$

Tags: calculus

I need help differentiating and simplying $$y = \sin^3(4x)cos^3(4x)$$
I got $$y'= 12(\sin4x)^2(\cos 4x)^2((\cos 4x)^2-(\sin 4x)^2)$$
but the answer is $$y'=3\sin^2 8x\cdot \cos 8x$$

Comment: Can you solve the problem following the given hint?

Comment: Sorry it doesn’t quite help me... am I supposed to use that identity to simplify it? I don’t know how to deal with the 4x

Comment: We can apply that here $$y = \sin^3(4x)\cos^3(4x)=(\sin(4x)\cos(4x))^3=\frac18 \ldots$$

Comment: Well done! You are welcome, Bye.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**

Recall that

$$2\sin \theta \cos \theta = \sin 2\theta$$

Answer (score 0):

Trig identities. If you have a you have a produce of $\sin$ and $\cos$ terms you can always reduce powers using the formulas
$$\cos(\theta+\phi)=\cos(\theta)\cos(\phi)-\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi),$$
$$\cos(\theta-\phi)=\cos(\theta)\cos(\phi)+\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi),$$
$$\sin(\theta+\phi)=\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)+\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta),\text{ and}$$
$$\sin(\theta-\phi)=\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)-\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta).$$